# Which grandson called me?

Tags: php, late-static-binding

Say I have this classes

```
class Grandpa
{
    public function call(){
        // Well, I want to know who calls me here
    }
}

class Father extends Grandpa
{
}

class GrandsonOne extends Father
{
}

class GrandsonTwo extends Father
{
}
```

Now, I call functions from the Grandson classes like so:

```
GrandsonOne::call();
GrandsonTwo::call();
```

How can I figure out who called?

Comment: I think your GradsonOne clss must extend to Father/Grandp.

Comment: When you call someone you don't make them guess who's calling do you? You tell them.

Comment: This was one of the big pains I had to deal with when building a PHP ORM. I think the feature was on the roadmap, so maybe it exists now, but back then I just had to suck it up and add a `$subclass` parameter to the parent method, then override it on the child. It was bad, but it was the only option at the time…

Comment: Probably the simplest way would be adding argument to call(), or overridden property, set in constructor, but maybe somebody knows better way?

Comment: You might want to edit your question! At the moment you'll simply get a fatal error trying to call those functions

Comment: From logical point of view, sense of extend is, that no matter which GrandSon::preparesMeal() , it is always Grandpa::doesDishwash() . So what matters it makes who made dinner, if extending Grandpa means dishwash is same job anyway?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I forgot to extend the Father. But you got the point.. Regarding one posible need for this is when you need some kind of overloading..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [get_called_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) function. From the PHP docs:-

```
Gets the name of the class the static method is called in.
```

So

```
class Grandpa
{
    public function call()
    {
        // Well, I want to know who calls me here
        echo get_called_class();
    }
}
```

will output the name of the called class.

Comment: That's what I needed. I don't know how I missed it in docs.. Thank you, Suleman!

Comment: Yes. It will work even if you are instantiating an object and calling the parent function.